# Shortcut to toggle between R console and the Editor within Intellij/Pycharm

Tags: r, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using the `R console` in Intellij. This is started automatically when invoking `Run` or `Debug` from within the Editor

[image]

From within the `R console` we can return to the Editor by hitting `ESC`.  How can we then go back to the `R console` from the Editor via a shortcut (and without hitting `Run` or `Debug` again)?

Note: `CMD-6` does open the `R Tool`

[image]

But that is not the `R console` instead some kind of messages window:

[image]

**Update** Here are the `Run` menu options

[image]

Comment: Does it help if you assign a keyboard shortcut to the tool window? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tool-windows.html#open.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Updated the question .

Comment: @CrazyCoder  What do you mean by `Run tool window` ?  I added the  `Run` menu options screenshot just in csae.

Comment: The problem is that Problems and R Console tool windows have the same shortcuts: https://i.imgur.com/sQ6RJ6C.png. Does it help if you change them?

Comment: Wow great eyes! Do you want to make an answer? if not I will and credit you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problems** and **R Console** tool windows have the same shortcuts, changing [the shortcuts for the tool windows](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tool-windows.html#open) should help:

[image: shortcuts]